# My HTML elements shrink with the window when it gets to really really small sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

[image]

```css
.topbarContainer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(235, 80, 106);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

As you can see, I have height set for the topbar. It is supposed to always be 50px. But when the window gets to be really really narrow, it no long respects the fixed height of 50px and just shrinks proportionally with window. How can this be fixed, so that the topbar always remains at 50px regardless?

Comment: It doesn't do that for me. Create a JSFiddle so we can see it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value for `flex` for any flex container is `flex: 0 1 auto` which means all items will shrink to fit the container but will not grow beyond the specified size (in this case 50px). You want to have a `flex-shrink` of 0 so in shorthand that would be `flex: 0 0 auto`.